# PM2 - Incorrect memory usage reading & possible memory leak with Node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, pm2

When my node js server is running via pm2, it has a higher memory usage reading than the actual memory heap in the application when inspected in DevTools. More so, the value under `memory` in pm2 slowly increases over time, possibly indicating some kind of memory leak. This slow increase in memory usage also cannot be observed in DevTools.

Any explanation and/or solutions to these two (seemingly) strange occurrences?

This is my DevTools

[image]

This is `pm2 list`

[image]

here is my `javascript` code

```
var SSE = require('sse');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('pathto/ssl.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('pathto/ssl.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('pathto/ssl.ca-bundle')
};


var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: "host",
    user: "user",
    password: "pass",
    database: "db"
});

async function connectandrun() {
    try {

        var server = https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
            var queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
            });

            if (queryData.connectionid) {
                var connecitonid = queryData.connectionid;
            } else {
                var connecitonid = "";
            }

            var myconection = "myconnecction" + connecitonid;
            var uuserjson = {};
            uuserjson[myconection] = {
                Data: {
                    Element: null
                }
            };

            schedule.scheduleJob('*/3 * * * * *', function() {
                var runninginstance = main(uuserjson, queryData, myconection, res).catch(console.error);
                runninginstance = null;
            });

            res.on("close", function() {
                res.end();
                uuserjson[myconection] = null;
                myconection = null;
                connecitonid = null;
            });
        });

        server.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function() {
            var sse = new SSE(server);
            sse.on('connection', function(client) {
                client.send('hi there!');
            });
        });

    } finally {}
}

connectandrun().catch(console.error);

async function main(uuserjson, queryData, myconection, res) {


    pool.getConnection(function(err, con) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            con.query("MYSQL QUERY",
                function(err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (result.length != 0) {
                        uuserjson[myconection] = {
                            Data: {
                                Element: result[0]
                            }
                        };

                        if (result[0]) {
                            res.write("retry: 30000\n\n" + "event: blanks\ndata: " + result[0] + "\n\n");
                        }
                    }

                    con.release();
                });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: and what about the memory leak? my application is always around 9-11MB. But pm2's memory seems to be increasing with time?

Comment: That I'm unsure of. It's hard to diagnose a memory leak without any code... It could be some pm2 overhead?

Comment: If you run your app without pm2, just regular ol `node index.js` or whatever, does the same thing happen?

Comment: that's the thing. It doesn't. and the values I see in the DevTools image above are the same. I'm going to put my code in the question.

Comment: What version of pm2 are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 4.2.1

Comment: There are a couple of threads I have found on this.. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34090834/10431732) [See this bug](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4134) Not sure if either of those will help.. but worth a shot.

Comment: The bug you referenced is interesting I'll look into it and comment my results here I added my js code also

Comment: After Googling around on this it def seems like something is up with pm2... and has been for a long time. [See the last comment here](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/2vbn8i/pm2_alternatives/cogoksa?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2xI) ..It may be worth giving something else a shot.. It looks like [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) may be a good alternative? Quickstart guide can be found [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/start/nodejs.html)

Comment: wow. it seems you're right. I'll do some testing and I'll let you know, so you can post an answer

Comment: Sounds good - I need to do some research as well since I have been using pm2 (but have memory limits set so if RAM researches a certain threshold I auto restart pm2).. so something like this would have been hard for me to catch. Nice find!!

Comment: Been running for a little while now with your suggestion and it's okay. Going to leave it for a few hours (as one of my tests only saw an increase after a few hours) and I'll return. Thanks for the suggestion. Will also do some digging up into pm2 and this alleged issue

Comment: Are you running on Phusion Passenger or did you start pm2 with that `gc` flag?

Comment: Okay, I can confirm there seemed to be some kind of leak on pm2. I tried it on Passenger and the memory stayed stagnant. In your answer, can you talk a little about the discussions and rumours out there about pm2 leaking? and provide the solutions / alternatives you found. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Nice work - I have just finished my write-up on this. Glad we (mostly you) were able to figure this out.  Hi-Five for teamwork! lol

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After teaming up with OP on this, it has been confirmed there is some sort of memory leak in `PM2`.

Please see the below 'write-up' on our findings:

---

***The Issue:***

- Slowly over time `PM2` uses more and more RAM

  - This points to some sort of memory leak

---

***Evidence & Rumors:***

- When running the application without `PM2`, just using `node myserver.js`, there is no evidence of RAM slowly increasing over time

  - RAM remains flat
  - The application that was used to test this theory is a small web app, in order to minimize the chance that the code contains a memory leak, and that the leak is in fact coming from `PM2`
- There have been 'rumors' and evidence of memory leaks in `PM2` for quite some time now - going back as far as 4 years (this answer was written in December 2019)
- [Someone describing why they stopped using `PM2`](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/2vbn8i/pm2_alternatives/cogoksa/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2xI)

  - *See last comment*
- [Thread where others are describing similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522163/node-js-memory-leak-with-pm2/34090834#34090834)

  - *That do not occur when `PM2` **is NOT** used*
- [Bug filed on `PM2` GitHub with a confirmed memory leak](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4134)

  - *This bug was filed this year [2019] and at the time of this writing has comments as recent as October, where someone describes how this is still an issue*

---

***PM2 Alternatives You Should Consider:***

- [`Phusion Passenger`](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) seems like a strong candidate for replacing `PM2`

  - [`Quick-start guide can be found here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/start/nodejs.html)
  - ***Phusion Passenger looks like the closest comparison to `PM2` and is where I would start***
  - No, I do not have any affiliation with Phusion Passenger...
- [`Forever`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

  - Does not seem like it is actively being maintained (in some of the issues filed on their GitHub people recommend using other apps)
- [`Nodemon`](https://nodemon.io/)

  - Not really 'apples to apples' with `PM2`, but hey, variety is the spice of life
- [`Naught`](https://github.com/andrewrk/naught)

  - Does not appear to be actively maintained and is kind of 'small' in terms of stars
- [Native `Node.js` cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

---

***`PM2` Workarounds/Band-Aids:*** (!not recommended to rely on these in Production!)

- [Set a Memory Threshold](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/memory-limit/) to auto-reload `PM2` once X amount of RAM has been consumed

  - This 'feature' is native within `PM2`
- [Use a Cron Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514444/restart-pm2-app-every-12h-with-cron) to restart `PM2` every X hours

  - [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501219/how-to-make-a-cron-job-with-pm2) of a Cron Job

Comment: 2 years later I still have this problem, man. https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5145

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The problem was that the `NextJS` build was not completed successfully. I did not notice this and tried to run `pm2`. Use command:

```
npm run build
```

And make sure the build completes successfully.